# Easiest way to prove that Hotelling $T^2$ follows $F$ distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

Suppose that $x_i \overset{iid}{\sim}N_p(\mu,\Sigma), (i=1,...,n)$. Define

$$T^2=n(\bar{x}-\mu)'S^{-1}(\bar{x}-\mu)$$

where $\bar{x}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ and $S=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(x_i-\bar{x})'$. Then, it is known that

$F=\frac{n-p}{p(n-1)}T^2 \sim F_{p,n-p}$

Could you explain the easiest way to prove this?